# What information could be extracted from a facebook image url?

Tags: image, facebook, url, hyperlink, privacy

Suppose I showed an expert an image url like this:

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10102210419817761&set=ecnf.4&type=3&theater

OR

https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10267763_10102210414947521_2931549383973829138_n.jpg?oh=d71a1c21c4b5f8b8ca42ce7647fff10d&oe=59F7421E

What information does that contain? Especially, could the url be used to detect the facebook profile that was logged in when the image was loaded? Can I compromise my own privacy online by linking others to random facebook images just by being logged into my profile while doing so?

Thanks!